# Sentry in Abp.io project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, sentry, abp

I want to use sentry in abp project and make steps correctly as follow but exceptions dosen't show in sentry dashboard (in issues page)
steps :
1- run command Install-Package Sentry.AspNetCore -Version 3.36.0
2- add this code

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
  .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
  {
      // Add the following line:
      webBuilder.UseSentry(o =>
      {
          o.Dsn = "https://xxxxxx.ingest.sentry.io/xxxx";
          // When configuring for the first time, to see what the SDK is doing:
          o.Debug = true;
          // Set TracesSampleRate to 1.0 to capture 100% of transactions for performance monitoring.
          // We recommend adjusting this value in production.
          o.TracesSampleRate = 1.0;
      });
  });
```

when I try

```
throw new Exception("Testing Sentry Exception");
```

no exception appear but when I try this

```
SentrySdk.CaptureException(new Exception("Test Exception by SentrySdk"));
```

it work and shown in issues page
what is the problem?
also when I do same steps on .net core project (not abp project) every thisg work fine

Comment: Here is answer => https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/17581

Answer (score 1):

When you call `webBuilder.UseSentry`, one of the things that extension method does is [register the SentryMiddleware](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/blob/db270dc1b048f46e650f7eb7cb6262ae53ad4e18/src/Sentry.AspNetCore/SentryWebHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L102), which is how Sentry generally captures unhandled exceptions in ASP.NET Core applications.

If the ABP framework doesn't make use of `IMiddleware` in the same way that ASP.NET Core does, you'll need to find another way to wire up a global exception handler for this.

It looks like there are lots of different ways you could do that. One way, since ABP [logs all unhandled exceptions](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/7.3/Exception-Handling#logging), would be to use [Sentry.Extensions.Logging](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/guides/extensions-logging/). Or possibly you could [create a custom `ExceptionSubscriber`](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/7.3/Exception-Handling#subscribing-to-the-exceptions).

I'd probably use `Sentry.Extensions.Logging` if it was me - that sounds like the easiest solution and gives you other benefits (like breadcrumbs for extra context where logs are created for non-error related events).

Comment: Sentry probably also needs to support these other error handling strategies so it works out of the box (assuming this isn't something Abp is 'stealing' from any other library): https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/issues/2611